# OSGi: Having the same Package path in two different Bundles

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

I got a `bundle1` that has the following packages:

```
com.anderson.servlet.osgi (exported) 
com.anderson.servlet
com.anderson.util (exported)
```

and a second one, `bundle2`, that looks like this:

```
com.anderson.jetty
com.anderson.servlet.osgi
```

and I also import `com.anderson.servlet.osgi` from `bundle1`.

Is it possible to merge both packages in `bundle2`?

Comment: Can't you just put your code/packages in a single bundle? What do you mean by "merge"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you import a package, that takes precedence over a private package with the same name that you may happen to have inside your bundle.

Why not just rename the private package in bundle2?

Comment: Thanks Neil, well this was just an example. The real code is much more and a lots of conflicts of this kind. And i don't have the whole source code. I think if i would change the packages name i wouldn't be able to change it in the .class or .jar. Right? I now this is a worst case ;)  Thank you very much anyway ! Your website (http://njbartlett.name/) was also very helpful.